# How to merge multiple rows belong to multiple columns to 1 row of multiple columns in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to merge multiple rows belong to multiple columns to 1 row of multiple columns in postgresql?
ie:
from
[image]

To:
[image]

Comment: Avoid give image as your reference

Comment: cannot copy paste tables here too long and the ASCII table generated is garbled

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `MAX` function with `group by`

```
SELECT user_id,
       firstseendate,
       lastseendate,
       MAX(IsActive7),
       MAX(IsActive7_14), 
       ....
FROM T
GROUP BY user_id,firstseendate,lastseendate
```

Comment: Perfect solution! Thanks!!